# Graph databases vs relationational database - algorithmic comlexity

Tags: mysql, algorithm, neo4j, graph-databases

I understand that graph databases REPRESENT relationships in a better way as compared to relational databases. As a result, we can visualize graph data better and also write less complex queries. But, are graph databases also better performance-wise? Please give an example query where the same query when executed in Neo4j can give faster results as compared to MySQL.

Let me try to explain my problem more clearly.
Here is an example from the book "The Definitive Guide to Graph Databases" form Neo4j. The query is for listing the products which can be recommended to a customer based on what his peer customers have purchased.

Cypher query:

```
MATCH (u:Customer {customer_id:'customer-one'})-
[:BOUGHT]->(p:Product)<- [:BOUGHT]-
(peer:Customer)-[:BOUGHT]->(reco:Product)

WHERE not (u)-[:BOUGHT]->(reco)

RETURN reco as Recommendation, count(*) as Frequency
ORDER BY Frequency DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The corresponding SQL query is (quite huge):

```
SELECT product.product_name as Recommendation, count(1) as Frequency
FROM product, customer_product_mapping, (SELECT cpm3.product_id,
cpm3.customer_id

FROM Customer_product_mapping cpm, Customer_product_mapping cpm2,

Customer_product_mapping cpm3

WHERE cpm.customer_id = ‘customer-one’

and cpm.product_id = cpm2.product_id

and cpm2.customer_id != ‘customer-one’

and cpm3.customer_id = cpm2.customer_id

and cpm3.product_id not in (select distinct product_id

FROM Customer_product_mapping cpm

WHERE cpm.customer_id = ‘customer-one’)

) recommended_products
WHERE customer_product_mapping.product_id = product.product_id
and customer_product_mapping.product_id in recommended_products.product_id
and customer_product_mapping.customer_id = recommended_products.customer_id
GROUP BY product.product_name
ORDER BY Frequency desc
```

The fact that the Cypher query is smaller does not mean that internally the query is executed in a more efficient way (i.e it is faster that an SQL query).

It would help if I be given an example where the use of graph databases **actually reduce the amount of traversals** than what it takes in MySQL. Better still if the answer is given in terms of the number of nodes, relation ships etc.

Thanks

Comment: Is google not working?

Comment: I didn't find resources which gave me the answer in terms of time complexity when the query is executed.

Comment: What is time complexity?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/mysql-vs-neo4j-large-scale

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the reply. The question has been edited. Kindly help.

Comment: I can't really help further, except to say that it's not really a fair comparison, because your MySQL queries appears to be deliberately engineered to be inefficient.

Comment: Plus, this bit is gibberish: `and customer_product_mapping.product_id in recommended_products.product_id`

Answer (score 0):

My sense is that your query is roughly equivalent to this - although I still suspect that there are more table instances than is strictly necessary...

```
SELECT p.product_name Recommendation
     , count(0) Frequency
  FROM product p
  JOIN customer_product_mapping m
    ON m.product_id = p.product_id
  JOIN Customer_product_mapping a
    ON a.product_id = m.product_id 
   AND a.customer_id = m.customer_id
  JOIN Customer_product_mapping cpm2
    ON cpm2.product_id = a.product_id 
   AND cpm2.customer_id != a.customer_id 
  JOIN Customer_product_mapping cpm3
    ON cpm3.customer_id = cpm2.customer_id
  LEFT
  JOIN Customer_product_mapping x
    ON x.product_id = cpm3.product_id
   AND x.customer_id = 'customer-one'
 WHERE cpm.customer_id = 'customer-one'
   AND x.product_d IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY p.product_name
 ORDER 
    BY Frequency desc
```

Comment: Does using this SQL query ensure faster processing than the equivalent in Cypher (i.e Neo4j)? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not qualified to comment on that.